# access device camera from lwc

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to access device camera from lwc. I am trying the below code but it is not working -

HTML

```
<template>
    <template if:true={video}>
        <video autoplay class="videoelement"></video>
    </template>
    <lightning-button label="clikc" onclick={capture}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

JS -

```
@track video;
@track canvas;

capture() {
    this.video = this.template.querySelector( '.videoelement' )

    if ( navigator.mediaDevices )
    {
        // access the web cam
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { video: true } )

            .then( function ( stream ) {

                this.video.srcObject = stream
            } )

            .catch( function ( error ) {
                document.body.textContent = 'Could not access the camera. Error: ' + error.name;
            } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Does any thirds party javascript will help or that also will face locker issue ?

Comment: technically speaking, you could wrap your lwc in an aura component with the api version set to 39 or bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Navigator's mediaDevices property is not available with Locker Service. however, here is an idea posted a few years ago which you can upvote

[Make navigator.mediaDevices available in Lightning Components API (WebRTC)](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CLRbQAO)

This might be confusing, given that Salesforce's [Locker API Viewer documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer) states otherwise, but the property itself returns undefined.

here, you can find the available properties from the navigator interface:
[image]